# Return array with class instances

Tags: ruby, arrays, class, variables

i have simple, how to return array with class instances ? I'm trying to return the array, but this variable return an empty array.

For example :

```
class Library

    def initialize
        @@books = []
    end

    def all
        @@books
    end

    def add_book(arg = {})
        @book = Book.new(arg)
        @@books << @book
    end

end

class Book

    attr_accessor :name, :year, :author, :content

    def initialize( arg = {})
        @name = arg[:name]
        @year = arg[:year]
        @author = arg[:author]
        @content = arg[:content]
    end

end
```

@@books is a Library class variable. I am using method add_book to put books into @books, but how can i return array of these instances ? Sorry for bad english.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you know what `@@x` vars are?

Comment: Also, what's `@@array`?

Comment: I'm newbie, @@var is a class variable.

Comment: It was a mistake in my post. I want to return array  with all instances of Book added in array.

Comment: "but this variable return an empty array". Where is it returning the empty array? What is the code you are testing?

Comment: Im testing this code, if you call Library.new.all , method all return empty array. Example : 


[15] pry(main)> Library.new.all
=> []

But i need return array with instances of class Book.

Comment: If you don't call `Library#add_book` before `Library.new.all` it's obvious (and correct) that `Library#all` returns an empty array.

Comment: Of course i call all method after i call method add_book. So, the array has some instances. For example

[#<Book:0x000001021da670 @author=nil, @content=nil, @name=nil, @year=nil>]

Comment: Ok, then show me the whole test script you are using.

Comment: https://github.com/bublifuk/testovanie/blob/master/kniznica.rb

Comment: Please include relevant code in your problem statement. Using snippets in comments and a github link aren't really appropriate ways to express a problem on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the method `new` to create a new object, ruby runs the `initialize` method. Since the `initialize` method sets `@@books` to an empty array, of course `Library.new.all` will return an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Class variables are shared by all instances of a class, so it doesn't make sense to be resetting it when you initialize a new `Library` as you'd be zeroing out the books stored in all other `Library` instances.  From your usage it looks like you want a plain instance variable:

```
class Library
  def initialize
    @books = []
  end

  # you could replace this method with a `attr_reader :books`
  def all
    @books
  end

  # consider changing the method signature to accept a Book instance
  def add_book(arg = {})
    @books << Book.new(arg)
  end
end
```